How do i use testandset() to synchronise two critical sections
I have to write two .c programs, both using the same shared memory. While one cycles from a to z, the other one has to print the same char. The task is to print the alphabet using testandset(). I'm not sure how to utilise the function so that it's completed.
this is the printing(consumer) program I tried
this is the cycling(producer) program I tried

I know what an [atomic] test & set operation is, but I've no idea what testandset() function you're referring to.

In any case, the question as posed is far too general, and no, we won't look at your image of your code.  The code you want to ask about should be presented as properly-formatted text directly in the question.  That will set the stage for asking a specific question about that code.

Why do you not want to use more traditional synchronization methods? Atomic operations are not enough for that

int testandset(int *mem){
int oldval;
oldval = mem;
*mem = 1;
return oldval;
}
